# QGIS point layer: Select first point in each category

Tags: qgis, point, expression, query

I have a point shapefile layer with several thousand points.  Each record has a timestamp field and another field which defines a category to which that record belongs.  There are about 200 different categories.  Is there a way to generate a query to select the first point of each category? A solution that sets a flag in a new calculated field would work, and then a query could be made based on that field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use select by expression with this expression - or you can use the expression as a condition in a larger expression:

```
time = array_min (array_agg ( time, group_by:=category))
```

`time` and `category` are the names of the corresponding attributes: replace these to match the names you have.

[image]