# Selecting rows in the attribute table depending on the time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter, time-series, time

Related to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427727/qgis-point-layer-select-first-point-in-each-category) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463696/filtering-elevation-changes-in-time-on-a-point-layer-in-qgis) questions, having the following table, I would like to select just one row per minute:

[image: table]

I have tried this expression, unsuccessfully:

> time = array_min (array_agg ( time, group_by:=ele))

How should I tweak it in order to just get one row per minute, as in here?

```
11/7/23 01:47:XX
11/7/23 01:48:XX
11/7/23 01:49:XX
```

(Note that the seconds are not important, they can be anything between 00 and 59).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a datetime field named `time`.

This will select first occurrence of each minute (each `year.month.day_hour.minute`),

ordered by time. Change `"time"` to the name of your datetime field.

```
array_first(array:=
array_agg(expression:=$id, group_by:=format_date( "time", 'yy.MM.dd_hh.mm'), order_by:="time"))=$id
```

[image]